# Dropdown click navigation problem in gatsby

Tags: reactjs

> I have a navbar, where I have a dropdown menu i.e., Phone, and it has
> 2 dropdown menus(samsung and nokia). On my page of PHONE I have 2
> sections(samsung and nokia). I want when I will click on sumsung it
> should scroll down to sumsung section and when I click Nokia it should
> scroll down down to nokia section. I have tried but it's not working.

**THIS IS THE CODE FOR NAVBAR**

```
<StyledNavItem >
              <UncontrolledDropdown setActiveFromChild>
          <DropdownToggle caret tag="a" className={clsx("nav-link","navbar_mobile")}>

          
          <MenuLink to="/phone/"> PHONE</MenuLink>
         
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem tag="a" href="#1" >SAMSUNG</DropdownItem>
    
              
               <DropdownItem tag="b" href="#2" >NOKIA</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </UncontrolledDropdown>
        </StyledNavItem>
```

**THIS IS THE CODE FOR PHONE PAGE**

```
<div id="1">SAMSUNG DATAS</div>
<div id="2">NOKIA DATA</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Link from react-router-dom to do any work for the anchor tag. You should never use anchor tag in reactapp because it refreshes the page hence taking the SPA element out of react itself. Learn more from here:https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start